# How to run main project in multi-project scala

Tags: scala

I've following Build code to have multi-project setup:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform._
import scalariform.formatter.preferences._
import sbtunidoc.Plugin._

object DirectorynameBuild extends Build {

addCommandAlias("rebuild", ";clean; compile; package")

    lazy val BoundedContext = Project(id = "BoundedContext",
                              base = file("."),
                              settings = commonSettings).aggregate(
                                persistence,
                                core,
                                biz,
                                protocol,
                                transport)

    lazy val persistence = Project(id = "BoundedContext-persistence",
                                settings = commonSettings,
                                 base = file("persistence")) dependsOn (protocol)

    lazy val core = Project(id = "BoundedContext-core",
                                settings = commonSettings,
                                 base = file("core")) dependsOn (
                                   persistence,
                                   biz,
                                   protocol)

    lazy val biz = Project(id = "BoundedContext-biz",
                                settings = commonSettings,
                                 base = file("biz")) dependsOn (protocol)


    lazy val protocol = Project(id = "BoundedContext-protocol",
                                settings = commonSettings,
                                 base = file("protocol"))

    lazy val transport = Project(id = "BoundedContext-transport",
                                settings = commonSettings,
                                 base = file("transport")) dependsOn(protocol)

  val ORGANIZATION    = "my.first.ddd.app"
  val PROJECT_NAME    = "directoryname"
  val PROJECT_VERSION = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  val SCALA_VERSION   = "2.11.4"

  val TYPESAFE_CONFIG_VERSION = "1.2.1"
  val SCALATEST_VERSION       = "2.2.2"
  val SLF4J_VERSION           = "1.7.9"
  val LOGBACK_VERSION         = "1.1.2"

  lazy val commonSettings = Project.defaultSettings ++
                            basicSettings ++
                            formatSettings ++
                            net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings

  lazy val basicSettings = Seq(
    version := PROJECT_VERSION,
    organization := ORGANIZATION,
    scalaVersion := SCALA_VERSION,

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.typesafe"     % "config"          % TYPESAFE_CONFIG_VERSION,
      "org.slf4j"        % "slf4j-api"       % SLF4J_VERSION,
      "ch.qos.logback"   % "logback-classic" % LOGBACK_VERSION % "runtime",
      "org.scalatest"   %% "scalatest"       % SCALATEST_VERSION % "test"
    ),

    scalacOptions in Compile ++= Seq(
      "-unchecked",
      "-deprecation",
      "-feature"
    ),

    /*javaOptions += "-Djava.library.path=%s:%s".format(
      sys.props("java.library.path")
    ),*/

    fork in run := true,

    fork in Test := true,

    parallelExecution in Test := false
  )

  lazy val formatSettings = scalariformSettings ++ Seq(
    ScalariformKeys.preferences := FormattingPreferences()
      .setPreference(IndentWithTabs, false)
      .setPreference(IndentSpaces, 2)
      .setPreference(AlignParameters, false)
      .setPreference(DoubleIndentClassDeclaration, true)
      .setPreference(MultilineScaladocCommentsStartOnFirstLine, false)
      .setPreference(PlaceScaladocAsterisksBeneathSecondAsterisk, true)
      .setPreference(PreserveDanglingCloseParenthesis, true)
      .setPreference(CompactControlReadability, true)
      .setPreference(AlignSingleLineCaseStatements, true)
      .setPreference(PreserveSpaceBeforeArguments, true)
      .setPreference(SpaceBeforeColon, false)
      .setPreference(SpaceInsideBrackets, false)
      .setPreference(SpaceInsideParentheses, false)
      .setPreference(SpacesWithinPatternBinders, true)
      .setPreference(FormatXml, true)
  )
//credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".credentials")

}
```

I've not defined `src/main/scala` in root folder.
I could run individual project using `sbt "project ****" run`
If I follow command: `sbt run` then I'm getting "No Main Class Detected"

I could see lagom framework is easily implementing the process I wanted. But I couldn't figure out the process.
What should I do to make the main project run without use of `src/main/scala/***App.scala`?